# Boostrap grid - same value to all resolutions

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

just a optimalization question. Is there any way to set the same value `class="col-xx-[value]` to all resolutions?

At the moment when I want to set same grid width I use:

```
class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"
```

Is there any way to simply use:

```
class="col-all-4"
```

or

```
class="col-4"
```

?

The code would be cleaner and it would look better + you woundn't have to type so much, especially when you have to use it on couple of elements.

NOTE: I didn't find any satisfying answer yet on the Internet.

EDIT: I guess I could use some JS with it:

```
if ($(*).hasClass('col-4').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('col-4');
  $(this).addClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4....');
}
```

Of course this JS code should be built better, but I think you'll get where I'm going with it.

Comment: Directly answer not possible in bootstrap grid.Cause all grid have its own width that's why if you want perfect responsive you should use those grid.

Comment: do you want non responsive grid in bootstrap ?

Comment: eg. I have a container, which is responsive and inside of it there are 2 columns (4 and 8 width) and I need them to always be this way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/):

> Each tier of classes scales up, meaning if you plan on setting the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.

So you only need to use `col-xs-4`.

Comment: It is really working! Since bootstrap's `@media` tags has only for example `(min-width: 768)` (without max-width which would block passing) then pass this width to higher resolutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could create it and it would be fairly simple. Bootstrap uses the @media tag to make these possible at different resolutions so you could have one big CSS class with the @media tag for each resolution and then copy what bootstrap has in for those particular classes. For example:

```
.col-4{
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  }
}
```

Personally I wouldn't bother, bootstrap is a nice framework and has all this built in, even if it is a few more characters of code. It also makes it much more maintainable and easier for someone else to look at your code and know what's going on.